# why network isolation allows more scale out in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans, azure-vm-scale-set

In Azure app service plan pricing, the tier 'Isolated' offers better scale out. The reason seems to be that it offers network isolation in addition to compute isolation. How is network isolation related to scale out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that network isolation has no relationship with scale-out since network isolation means running your web app on dedicated Azure VM on the dedicated virtual network which provides network isolation on top of computing isolation to your apps.

A scale-out operation is an equivalent of creating multiple copies of your web site and adding a load balancer automatically provided by the platform to distribute the demand between them. Scale-out means adding instances to handle the increased load.

In my opinion, that is just a different pricing tier offering different scale-out instance counts. Each pricing tier has a maximum number of instances.

Ref: [Azure App Service plan overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans)